# Finding branches of n-ary graph tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Given a n-ary tree, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29, described by a graph with vertices and edges, I would like to split the tree into sub graphs.  Each sub graph would be a branch of the n-ary tree.  The sub graph would contain adjacent edges with vertices of a degree of two.  The start condition would be a vertex with a degree greater than two.  If non-terminating the end condition would also be a vertex with a degree greater than two.  If the branch is terminating (a leaf) the end condition would be a vertex with a degree of one.

What algorithm might accomplish this?  Also would there be a graph library that would support this?  A c# implementation would be ideal.

```
public class VoronoiGraph
{
    public HashSet Vertizes = new HashSet();
    public HashSet Edges = new HashSet();
}
```

See this link for a typical medial axis that I am trying to decompose.
http://spacesymmetrystructure.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/medialax.gif?w=510&h=360

Comment: Is this a homework question?  Also, can you give us some code for the graph API so that the answers will be consistent?  Just define the `GraphVertice` class and the names of a few methods we can use.

Comment: Not a homework problem.  I am trying to split branches of a medial axis described from a group of voronoi vertices that lie in a closed polygon.  I would like to split the them so I can fit a geometric component to a group of vertices for each graph.

 `code`public class VoronoiGraph
 {
  public HashSet Vertizes = new HashSet();
  public HashSet Edges = new HashSet();
 }

Comment: What do you mean by "adjacent edges with vertices of degree one"? This seems to imply a forest of pairs of connected vertices with each vertex connected to a single another vertex. In a tree only the leaf nodes have a degree one, and the parent of a leaf node has degree greater than one assuming it is not the root.

Comment: Yes VSOverFlow you are right.  Thanks for correcting me.  I have edited the question for the correct degrees for the problem.  I have also added a link to a typical medial axis of a closed boundary, which is what I am trying to split.